# rails4, NameError in Zic#index, routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
undefined local variable or method `nov_tisk_revij_index' for #<#<Class:0x007f361551b858>:0x007f3615519c60>
```

Hey guys, I'm setiing up a rails app and can't figure out what's wrong. I used `rails g controller nov_tisk_revij index show` to create my views and controller and now I can't link to it. If you can spot what I'm doing wrong, I'd be very grateful, don't want to remake this as is took a fair amount of work.

rake routes returns:

```
     Prefix Verb URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
nov_tisk_revij_index GET  /nov_tisk_revij/index(.:format) nov_tisk_revij#index
 nov_tisk_revij_show GET  /nov_tisk_revij/show(.:format)  nov_tisk_revij#show
           zic_index GET  /zic/index(.:format)            zic#index
                root GET  /                               zic#index
```

my html:

```
<%= link_to 'Novi izvodi tiskanih revij', nov_tisk_revij_index %>
```

routes:

```
  get 'nov_tisk_revij/index'
  get 'nov_tisk_revij/show'
  get 'zic/index'
```

I tried adding `resources :nov_tisk_revij` into routes, and it still didn't work, just created additional routes for views I do not have.

controller:

```
class NovTiskRevijController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

I'm using rails4 with ruby 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'Novi izvodi tiskanih revij', nov_tisk_revij_index_path %>
```

works